# Changing 'time' column to 'datetime'

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, datetime

in Rails 3 app I have table subscription_schedules, in which there is a column of 'time' type

example record lokks like this:

```
#<Subscription::Schedule id: 3504, subscription_id: 4961, scheduled_at: "2000-01-01 01:11:00", primary: true, created_at: "2015-09-28 01:13:34", updated_at: "2015-09-28 01:13:34", active: true>
```

What I want to do is to convert scheduled_at to datetime. I decided to add new column `'temp_scheduled_at'`, save all `'scheduled_at'` to it, change `'scheduled_at'` to datetime with `change_column()` method , and later move whats in `'temp_scheduled_at'` to `'scheduled_at'`.

It looks like this:

```
add_column :subscription_schedules, :temp_scheduled_at, :datetime
Subscription::Schedule.select {|s| s.subscription}.each do |schedule|
        schedule.temp_scheduled_at = schedule.scheduled_at
      schedule.scheduled_at = nil
      begin
          schedule.save!
      rescue => e
        puts schedule.id
      end
    end

change_column :subscription_schedules, :scheduled_at, :datetime
```

Unfortunately thats where the troubles start. After calling `Subscription::Scheudule.all` later on, I get

```
Invalid date in field 'scheduled_at': 2001-00-00 00:00:00
```

I really have no idea what is causing this error, before changing column type record with 'invalid date' looked like this:

```
#<Subscription::Schedule id: 2555, subscription_id: 4102, scheduled_at: "2000-01-01 05:00:00", primary: true, created_at: "2015-06-23 16:12:01", updated_at: "2015-06-23 16:12:01", active: true>
```

Comment: scheduled_at column already contain datetime value. Can you post current output and desired output

Comment: it looks like it, but in mysql it is column 'time', also in rails only hours, minutes and seconds are stored. current output looks as above, what i want is datetime column which i later fill with information

Comment: do you want any dummy date associate with that time ?

Comment: i want to convert (manually) the time, i dont know what you mean by dummy date in this context

Comment: i meant, you are getting only time without date. then how do i add what date with that time

Comment: I'm calculating this in migration but only after the error here is raised

Comment: i guess your record set have invalid datetime value in scheduled_at field.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use it in mysql query. You can change time to datetime in mysql query and refered as new column name. Its very easy compare to progrmming way. for ex-

```
select schedule_at, now() as temp_scheduled_at from tablename;
```

You can read more date time function [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_current-time)